# Ask RMagick to send a direct command to ImageMagick

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

Some options of ImageMagick are not supported by RMagick. Also sometimes it is in fact more convenient to use ImageMagick. Is there a method (of the Image object) that allows you to send commands directly to ImageMagick using the command line interface?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be ok for you to use `system` or system call via backticks (or similar)?

You may also extend `Magick::Image` to do it easier.

My example code add a method `convert` to call the convert-command of imagemagick for the actual image. The action to be performed must be added.

```
require 'rmagick'
module Magick
  class Image
      def convert( cmd )
        `convert #{self.filename} #{cmd}` 
      end
  end
end

picname = Dir['*.jpg'].first
img = Magick::Image.read(picname).first

img.convert('x.png')
```