# Install Rmagick with default 8 bits

Tags: ruby, heroku, rubygems, imagemagick, rmagick

By default Rmagick (based on ImageMagick) is built with a `--with-quantum-depth=16` (16 bits per channel). This is not necessary for my application, and I fail to see how to install Rmagick/ImageMagick and make it use just 8 bits per channel.

I am willing to install this on my local machine (Ubuntu 12.04) and Heroku using Gemfile.

Comment: Wouldn't that just be `./configure --with-quantum-depth=8` with [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org/script/advanced-unix-installation.php)?

Comment: ImageMagick is installed when installing Rmagick I guess. I didn't install ImageMagick by hand on Heroku...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quantum depth](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Color.html) is defined at build time, but can be adjusted dynamically during run time. See [-depth 8](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#depth) option for ImageMagick, and [self.depth = 8](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/info.html#depth) in RMagick.

```rb
img = Image.new(123,321) {
     self.depth = 8
}
```

Comment: Do you know how could I save it to 8 bits? Say I manipulate several images and I am not sure how many bits, until when I save I would like to save it with just eight bits. With ImageMagick you can do -colors 255, do you know in Rmagick?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338185/ask-rmagick-to-send-a-direct-command-to-imagemagick) may be a better solution for you. If everything in Ruby is an object, just subclass the `Magick` module, do what you need, and walk away. Else, setting the `-colors` is just another [image attribute](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/imageattrs.html#colors).